# Getting style information using XSSFSheetXMLHandler

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I'm reading very large (150Mb) xlsx files.  I have my own XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler to extract the data of interest. (It does execute pleasingly quickly).   However, for each cell the overridden method

```
cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment)
```

only gets me the cell reference and value.

**How can I get the style (and hence foreground fill color) applied to this cell?**  XSSFSheetXMLHandler gives me the StylesTable data - so I know what styles exist, all I don't have is any kind of pointer from each cell to the StylesTable.  The only solution appears to be to extend XSSFSheetXMLHandler and then start reverse engineering the SAX parsing.

Is this the only approach?

Answer (score 1):

Grab the source code for XSSFSheetXMLHandler from the Apache POI source; it's fairly straightforward.

I found it made more sense to clone this class to do everything I needed than to pass in a SheetHandler. I was able to achieve everything (styling, colours, borders, merged cells, etc.) that I had done with the user API, before I ran into memory issues processing large XLSX files.

For example, I made a slight change to the "c" handler under startElement. I save the XSSFCellStyle as a property of the class, and then I can use it in the cellHandler.

```
// c => cell
        else if ("c".equals(localName)) {
            // Set up defaults.
            this.nextDataType = xssfDataType.NUMBER;
            this.formatIndex = -1;
            this.formatString = null;
            cellRef = attributes.getValue("r");
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            String cellStyleStr = attributes.getValue("s");
            if (stylesTable != null) {
                if (cellStyleStr != null) {
                    int styleIndex = Integer.parseInt(cellStyleStr);
                    this.cellStyle = stylesTable.getStyleAt(styleIndex);
                } else if (stylesTable.getNumCellStyles() > 0) {
                    this.cellStyle = stylesTable.getStyleAt(0);
                }
            }
```

And use it later (e.g. in cellHandler):

```
XSSFFont cellFont = cellStyle.getFont();
        if( cellFont.getXSSFColor() != null ) {
            // set hex colour in style. drop first 2 hex characters since they represent alpha
            styles.put(CSS_COLOR, "#"+cellFont.getXSSFColor().getARGBHex().substring(2));
        }
```

Merged cells:

```
 else if ("mergeCell".equals(localName)) {
            if ( attributes.getValue("ref") != null ) {
                CellRangeAddress cra = CellRangeAddress.valueOf(attributes.getValue("ref"));
                // store merged cell ranges in hashmap?     
            }
        }
```